# android.util.Pair as key in HashMap

Tags: java, android

Is it Ok to use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html this for keys in HashMap? 
It since to me that this class provides valid implementation for equals() and hashCode(). Am I right?

Comment: I would say yes, and i would say that you can know for sure by testing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Pair supports equals and hashcode, you can safely use it as a key.

I put together a very simple JUnit test to satisfy myself that this is true & it passed.

```
public final void testPairAsHashMapKey() {

    HashMap<Pair<Integer, Integer>, String> map = new HashMap<Pair<Integer, Integer>, String>();

    Pair<Integer, Integer> p1 = new Pair<Integer, Integer>(0, 0);
    Pair<Integer, Integer> p2 = new Pair<Integer, Integer>(0, 0);
    Pair<Integer, Integer> p3 = new Pair<Integer, Integer>(5, 3);
    Pair<Integer, Integer> p4 = new Pair<Integer, Integer>(3, 5);

    map.put(p1, "foo");
    assertEquals(1, map.size());
    assertEquals("foo", map.get(p1));

    map.put(p2, "new_foo");
    // p2.equals(p1) so map will not grow but value will update
    assertEquals(1, map.size());
    assertEquals("new_foo", map.get(p2));

    map.put(p3, "bar");
    assertEquals(2, map.size());
    assertEquals("bar", map.get(p3));

    map.put(p4, "test");
    assertEquals(3, map.size());
    assertEquals("test", map.get(p4));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The equal method checks the two objects for equality by delegating to their respective equals methods.

If you override your objects' equals method according to your purpose everything will be ok.
It is same for hashCode but dont change it. Default hashCode should be ok.

Comment: You should ALWAYS override hashcode when you override equals, and vice-versa. _"By definition, if two objects are equal, their hash code must also be equal. If you override the equals() method, you change the way two objects are equated and Object's implementation of hashCode() is no longer valid. Therefore, if you override the equals() method, you must also override the hashCode() method as well."_

Comment: yes it is completely right but if your code doesnt use hashCode it doesnt matter. For instance this code runs perfectly even if i dont override hashCode function.
class Test {
 private int i;
 
 public Test(int i) {
  this.i = i;
 }
 
 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object o)
 {
  return this.i == ((Test)o).i;
 }
}

public class Main {
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  Test t1 = new Test(1);
  Test t2 = new Test(2);
  Test t22 = new Test(2);
  
  System.out.println(t1.equals(t2));
  System.out.println(t2.equals(t22)); 
  
 }
}

Comment: You're wrong because if you override equals, you should respect the contract `x1.equals(x2) => (x1.hashCode() == x2.hashCode())`.

Comment: Ok. The output of my example is false true. You can copy and execute that code snippet if you want to be sure regarding this issue. I dont know internal mechanism of compiler especially how to handle this but it is possible that compiler enhances my codes in order to make it correct.

Comment: I'm saying that if `t2.equals(t22);` returns `true`, it **must** implies that `t2.hashCode() == t22.hashCode();` returns `true`. Is this the case in your example ? No, because you did'nt override accordingly the `hashCode()` method in your class.

Comment: I say t1.equals(t2) returns false but t2.equals(t22) returns true. I only changed equals() method not hashCode(). I see you still insist on hashCode ok i respect, Can you explain how does my example still work correctly ?

Comment: Ok, you override equals that's fine and I didn't said it was false, but that's not the point I want to explain. Let's take another approach. Imagine that you use an HashSet to store your objects. An hashset doesn't allow duplicates, i.e it contains no pair of elements `e1` and `e2` such that `e1.equals(e2)`. So according to you what objects should the set contains if I had all of them  in the Set ?

Comment: See also this to understand. http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/why-always-override-hashcode-if-overriding-equals/20

Comment: Yes, you are right. For hashset all of them will get in set because of set uses hashCode for comparison. Actually i emphasized this in my second comment _"dont change it if your code doesnt use hashCode"_. Admittedly your approach is better than mine because it will more robust and correct. Thank you for discussion